# Spring Security anonymous user has acces to every url

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm developing gwt application which I want to secure using spring-security. I have users data in database and UserService is responsible for getting particular User. I have followed this  [tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/12/securing-gwt-apps-with-spring-security.html)

AuthenticationProvider:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired UserService userService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

        User user = userService.findByUserName(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
        String storedPass = user.getPassword();
        if (!storedPass.equals(password)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid password");
        }
        Authentication customAuthentication = new CustomUserAuthentication(user, authentication);
        customAuthentication.setAuthenticated(true);

        return customAuthentication;
    }

   @Override
   public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
      return     UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
   }
}
```

CustomAuthentication

```
    public class CustomUserAuthentication implements Authentication {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3091441742758356129L;

        private boolean authenticated;

        private final GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority;
        private final Authentication authentication;
        private final User user;

        public CustomUserAuthentication(User user, Authentication authentication) {
            this.grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().name());
            this.authentication = authentication;
            this.user = user;
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            authorities.add(grantedAuthority);
            return authorities;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCredentials() {
            return authentication.getCredentials();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getDetails() {
            return authentication.getDetails();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getPrincipal() {
            return user;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAuthenticated() {
            return authenticated;
        }

        @Override
        public void setAuthenticated(boolean authenticated) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            this.authenticated = authenticated;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return user.getUsername();
        }

    }
```

security context:

```
<s:http auto-config="true" create-session="always" >
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/index.html" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <s:logout logout-success-url="/login.html"/>
    <s:form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/index.html" authentication-failure-url="/login.html" />
</s:http>

<s:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <s:authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
</s:authentication-manager>

<bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="com.example.server.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider" />
```

Everything works fine, spring intercept call to index.html i need to log and it redirects me back to index.html. The problem is when i log out and then go to index.html once again I just simply get access to it. I figured out that:

```
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    System.out.println("Logged as: " + auth.getName());
```

prints anonymousUser after logout. This code prints my user name when I log in again so I suppose that there is something wrong with intercepting anonymous user. Does anyone knows how to intercept anonymous user?

Comment: Where do you invalidate the session when you logged out?

Comment: @TheEwook i am just using <a href="/j_spring_security_logout">Logout</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
 <s:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

You can use:

```
<s:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY,ROLE_USER" />
```

That should make Spring Security deny access to the anonymous user. Of course, that implies you also need to add one of these:

```
<s:intercept-url pattern="/url_that_should_be_accessible_to_anonymous_user" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```

For every pattern that anonymous users should be able to access. Typically,  login pages, error pages, static resources (images, PDF, etc).

Comment: I still have acces but rpc calls throws exception. Exception message contains login page content.

Comment: @Up ok this is propably caused by gwt development mode. When i deploy my application on production serwer acces to index.html is intercepted