# Spring Security provides anonymous acces to all pages instead only one

Tags: spring-security

I my sprig-security.xml I've got:

```
<security:http auto-config='true' create-session="stateless">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/registrate**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <security:http-basic />
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
</security:http>
```

The problem is that all protected pages are available for anonymous users, the only way to get access denied is to enter bad user's credentials, but with no credentials it will pass.
How to give anonymous user access to only "/registrate" page and give access to authorized user for rest of resources.

I've looked in Spring Docs and in the web. The only solution I've found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379521/spring-security-anonymous-user-has-acces-to-every-url) and it didn't work for me.

Comment: add
<security:form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/" />

Comment: @SafwanHijazi Thanks. But I think It won't work. The thing is that there's no login.html page it's a REST service.

Comment: Do you want to protect access to rest service?

Comment: @SafwanHijazi Yes, and I almost succeeded with that. If I remove line with intercept-url pattern="/registrate**" it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the program I tested my service with. The program was SoapUI 5.1.3.